# React App in modal not started second time

Tags: html, reactjs

I have custom html/jQuery application and I want to show modal with React application.
Modal content is from ajax call and its like:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="module" src="react-app.js"></script>
</div>
```

When I call ajax and receive html modal will show my React App. Problem is that I close modal, html is deleted and call ajax second time. I got same html markup but React App will not show.
Why?
My React App is like:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);
root.render(<App />);
```

I tested also this:

```
async function reloadModule() {
  const container = document.getElementById('root');
  const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(container);
  root.render(<App />);
}

reloadModule();
```

What to do to show my React App second time or more time? Not only first time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding query in JS loading like this:

```
<script type="module" src="react-app.js?hash=randomstring"></script>
```

and it work as expected. Its not perfect solution but most simple.